# U-boot driver registration

Tags: c, u-boot

I could see there are two types of driver registrations( `U_BOOT_DRIVER` and `UCLASS_DRIVER`) in the U-boot source. Some drivers registering using only [U_BOOT_DRIVER](https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/latest/source/drivers/power/pmic/pmic_tps65217.c) and some drivers registering using both [U_BOOT_DRIVER and UCLASS_DRIVER](https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/latest/source/drivers/core/root.c). Can you help to understand when to register using both and when to register using only U_BOOT_DRIVER.

Answer (score 0):

Every driver belongs to a class. Available classes are listed in the [`uclass_id` enum](https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/latest/source/include/dm/uclass-id.h#L13). Class drivers (`UCLASS_DRIVER`) handle features common to every driver in that class, while normal drivers (`U_BOOT_DRIVER`) handle specific devices.

For example, the TPS65217 driver you linked to is in the `UCLASS_PMIC` class; the corresponding class driver can be found in [pmic-uclass.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/latest/source/drivers/power/pmic/pmic-uclass.c#L7).